# How to Import/load password protected excel work book to tables using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an excel file and I have to load the excel data into SQL tables through an SSIS package.

I have tried creating a package and added excel connection manager and excel source but the excel is showing up an error and name of the excel sheet in the drop down is not loading...

Please help. Let me know if you need any further information. Thanks!

Comment: There is a password property on the connection manager, did you set that?

Comment: @JoeC Yes I have set that but it is not working after setting it.

Comment: I was able to Import Data from a password protected excel file by opening the file in excel, entering the password and then starting the SQL Server Import Wizard using SSMS with SQL Server 2014.

Not sure how you could use or replicate this in an SSIS package.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is not possible to connect to a pw protected excel file even though there is that property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139836.aspx

I did find a workaround though using powershell to open and save as...
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic885800-148-1.aspx